# Spring mvc with hibernate, how can I add a restful service endpoint?

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc

So I have spring mvc up and running with hibernate.

I'm reading how I can add Restful endpoints using the @ResponseBody: http://blog.springsource.com/2010/01/25/ajax-simplifications-in-spring-3-0/

So if I have an endpoint like:

```
http://localhost:8080/services/user/get/1
```

I will fetch a user with userId=1, how will I return and how will it convert my user object to  an XML representation?

Do I have to do something special in my User.java class for this to work?

Comment: Maybe try with an XML request and see what happens. The various "Postr"-like browser plugins are great for playing with RESTful APIs.

Answer (score 1):

The way I've done this in the past is as follows:

- Annotate your `User` class with [JAXB annotations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4880937/jaxb-annotations) (for example `@XmlRootElement`)
- Hook up a suitable Spring `HttpMessageConverter` [as in this documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.0.M3/spring-framework-reference/html/ch18s02.html#d0e29963)
- When sending a request, make sure to include an Accept header: `Accept: application/xml`

By doing this, you'll have total control of how your `User` gets "flattened" to XML, but you're leaving all the hard work (determining the correct endpoint, data conversion) to Spring.

Answer (score 1):

The conversion of method return types annotated with @ResponseBody into actual HTTP Responses is accomplished by implementations of the [HttpMessageConverter](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/converter/HttpMessageConverter.html) interface.  Spring comes with an [implementation for JAXB](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/converter/xml/Jaxb2RootElementHttpMessageConverter.html).  So if you can annotate your User class with JAXB annotations, that may work for you.  If User is a Hibernate annotated Entity, adding JAXB to it also can get hairy.  You may want to create an intermediate object for the JAXB.

Alternately you can use any arbitrary Marshaller by using the [Marshalling Message Converter](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/converter/xml/MarshallingHttpMessageConverter.html).  There are quite a few implementations of [Marshaller](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/oxm/Marshaller.html) built in to choose from, or you can always write your own.

You turn on converters by registering them on the AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter (in the dispatcher servlet xml:

```
<bean id="xmlMessageConverter" class="org.springframework.http.converter.xml.Jaxb2RootElementHttpMessageConverter">
    <property name="supportedMediaTypes" value="text/xml" />
</bean>

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter">
    <property name="messageConverters">
        <list>
            <ref bean="xmlMessageConverter"/>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

Spring MVC have integration with XStream (convert objects to XML)

This is an interesting approach: http://www.stupidjavatricks.com/?p=54

You have to set the `XStreamAlias` annotation in your class and configure Spring to use XStream.

I also indicate Spring that the output is xml. In your url example that should be:

```
http://localhost:8080/services/user/get/1.xml
```