# Create XML data to be returned in restful webservice in java

Tags: java, web-services, rest

How do I create my own xml data to be used with Restful web service in Java? I did create a string file using `StringBuilder` but when I tried consuming at the client side there is always a problem extracting the attributes from it there is always an error.

Listed below is my code;

```
Employee emp0 = new Employee("David", "Finance");
Employee emp1 = new Employee("Smith", "HealthCare");
Employee emp2 = new Employee("Adam", "Information technology");
Employee emp3 = new Employee("Stephan", "Life Sciences");

map.put("00345", emp0);
map.put("00346", emp1);
map.put("00347", emp2);
map.put("00348", emp3);

@GET
@Path("{id}")
@Produces({"application/xml"})
public String find(@PathParam("id") String id) {

    Employee emp = (Employee) map.get(id);
    if (emp != null) {
        StringBuilder br = new StringBuilder();
        br.append("<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>").append(nl);
        br.append("<Employee>").append(nl);
        br.append("<Emp-ID>").append(id).append(" </Emp-ID >").append(nl);
        br.append("<Name>").append(emp.getName()).append(" </Name>").append(nl);
        br.append("<dept>").append(emp.getDept()).append(" </Department>").append(nl);
        br.append("</Employee>");
        return br.toString();
    } else {
        return "Unknown id";
    }
}
```

I have a POJO by the name of Employee with Name and Department as attributes as well. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you add an `@XmlRootElement(name="Employee")` annotation on your `Employee` class then you could do the following:

```
@GET
@Path("{id}")
@Produces({"application/xml"})
public Employee find(@PathParam("id") String id) {

    return (Employee) map.get(id);

}
```

Then the `@XmlElement` annotation can be used to override the element names.  You can also leverage a JAX-RS `Response` object to return a status code rather than a `String` error message.

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/08/creating-restful-web-service-part-45.html

Answer (score 1):

i would suggest you use JAXB annotations on your Employee class instead of this stringbuilder exercise.
this [link](http://www.vogella.com/articles/JAXB/article.html) should help you get started

and this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4880937/jaxb-annotations) should answer any further questions